# Nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, api

I'm having trouble handling a nested array I get as result from an API. `Print_r($result, true);` returns an array looking like this (only much longer):

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [return] => Array
        (
            [sellorders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [sellprice] => 0.00000059
                            [quantity] => 1076.00000000
                            [total] => 0.00063484
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [sellprice] => 0.00000060
                            [quantity] => 927.41519000
                            [total] => 0.00055645
                        )
                )

            [buyorders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [buyprice] => 0.00000058
                            [quantity] => 6535.77328102
                            [total] => 0.00379075
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [buyprice] => 0.00000057
                            [quantity] => 118539.39620414
                            [total] => 0.06756746
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

I need to grab the 3 values (sellprice/buyprice, quantity, total) from the first index of both arrays (sellorders and buyorders) and store them in variables ($sellprice, $sellquantity, $selltotal).

The full example php script I'm using can be found on the bottom of [this page](https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/api). Could anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: So store `$sellprice = array($result['return']['sellorders'][0]['sellprice'], $result['return']['sellorders'][1]['sellprice'],$result['return']['buyorders'][0]['sellprice'],$result['return']['buyorders'][1]['sellprice'])` and same thing for the other two....

Comment: What code have you tried to accomplish this? You've only linked to a generic example not written by you...

Comment: @MattBrowne I've tried alot but it's like building a rocketship as a hobby carpenter. I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: @hustlerinc That's understandable, but in the future please post at least some of the code you have tried, even if it's minimal and doesn't work at all...it helps those answering to see where you went wrong, and could lead to answers that will help you learn better. On StackOverflow you'll commonly see people asking "what have you tried?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, arrays can more or less have infinite dimensions. You can go deeper within an array's dimensions by adding another set of square brackets. For example,

```
$array['deep']['deeper']['deepest'][0];
```

Assuming the indexes in the sellorders and buyorders are the same in your array, you could do

```
$sellprice = $result['return']['sellorders'][0]['sellprice'];
$sellquantity = $result['return']['sellorders'][0]['quantity'];
$selltotal = $result['return']['sellorders'][0]['total'];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks, now I have something to work with. :)

Answer (score 1):

The value should look something like this:

```
$sellprice = $array['return']['sellorders'][0]['sellprice']
```

You might want to think about how you iterate over these nested arrays in order to pick out all the values. Furthermore, if you have control over the output I might be better to use a different data structure to enable easier processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of the nested arrays by adding another pair of square brackets with the appropriate index at the end:

```
$array['outer']['inner'];
```

It's up to you to transfer this knowledge to your specific array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go thru all of those arrays... try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array['return']['sellorders']); $i++) {
  $this_array = $array['return']['sellorders'][$i];
  var_dump($this_array); // it includes sellprice, quantity and total for each entity now.
}
```

**use the same method as above for buyorders as well.**